# В Debian не добавляется пользователь в root группу

Tags: debian, sudo, права-доступа

На виртуальную машину VMWare поставил Debian 11. При попытке выполнить под пользователем действия с командой `root` естественно пишет

> user is not in the sudoers file.The incident will be reported

Пишу `su -`, под рутом выполняю `usermod -aG sudo user`, делаю пользователем logout, захожу обратно, пишу под пользователем `sudo -i` и после пароля всё равно выдаёт `is not in the sudoers file`. Более того теперь каждый раз, даже после перезагрузки виртуалки и авторизации этим пользователем рабочий стол всегда старнует с запущеным терминалом и файловым менеджером - то есть с чем вылогинился первый раз, с тем оно теперь всегда стартует. Графическая оболочка Xfce.

На физической машине таких проблем нет (на ноут ставил этот же debian).

Что это за баг и как его починить?

Comment: sudoers file и группа sudo это разные вещи.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, хорошо, но в чём проблема то - `usermod` чего не работает? После всех манипуляций не даёт под пользователем выполнять команды под sudo

Comment: Ну посмотрите что там в `/etc/sudoers` написано